# Add auto-focus on barcode scanner with PhoneGap (Monaca)

Tags: cordova, barcode-scanner, autofocus, monaca

I've been using Monaca to create a mobile app for Android and iOS. I have just enabled Monaca's plugin BarcodeScanner. The scans are good and fast, but there is one drawback. The camera only focuses on launch. The problem is that the user has likely not already targeted the barcode when they tap to launch the camera. Is there a way to enable something like a constant auto-focus feature with PhoneGap? (Like the one that iOS camera already has OR a tap-to-focus feature)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean that it only focuses immediately after the button is clicked and not focuses anymore after that unless the screen is touched? If so, it is not true. I've tried the plugin. It constantly auto-focuses. Correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this only happens on iPhone 4 or earlier for some reason. Other devices keep refocusing automatically. As far as I got searching, there is no way to change that in this particular plugin.